Unable to access 'Set-Cookie' attribute in Flutter received from HTTP server
Flutter code
http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, String>{
            "email": "pavitra@email.com",
            "password": "admin1234"
          },
        ));

    print(response.headers);

backend(Node.js)
  res.cookie('token', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay),
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  });
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ msg: 'User logged in' });


Cors setup in server.js
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ['Set-Cookie', 'cookies', 'Cookies'],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

API response in POSTMAN
I have tried many solutions but I get null when I try access response.headers["Set-Cookie"]
